# How to get aggregate sum in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark. I am using Spark 2.2 version.
I have below input data in JSON format.

```
{"a_id":6336,"b_sum":10.0,"m_cd":["abc00053"],"td_cnt":[10.0]}
{"a_id":6336,"b_sum":10.0,"m_cd":["abc00053"],"td_cnt":[5.0]}
{"a_id":6336,"b_sum":10.0,"m_cd":["abc00054"],"td_cnt":[20.0]}
{"a_id":6336,"b_sum":10.0,"m_cd":["abc00056"],"td_cnt":[30.0]}
{"a_id":6339,"b_sum":10.0,"m_cd":["abc00051"],"td_cnt":[12.0]}
{"a_id":6339,"b_sum":10.0,"m_cd":["abc00057"],"td_cnt":[7.0]}
{"a_id":6339,"b_sum":10.0,"m_cd":["abc00055"],"td_cnt":[10.0]}
{"a_id":6339,"b_sum":10.0,"m_cd":["abc00058"],"td_cnt":[20.0]}
{"a_id":6339,"b_sum":10.0,"m_cd":["null"],"td_cnt":[null]}
```

I want group by the records on **a_id** and **b_sum** columns and collect list of **m_cd** and respective **td_cnt** records in

```
array(["abc00053":15.0,"abc00054":20.0,"abc00056":30.0]).
```

Then get the sum of **td_cnt** column values as a **td_cnt** new column in dataframe.

**Expected output:**

```
{"a_id":6336,"b_sum":10.0,"td_cnt":["abc00053":15.0,"abc00054":20.0,"abc00056":30.0],"td_cnt_sum":65}
{"a_id":6339,"b_sum":10.0,"td_cnt":["abc00051":12,"abc00057":7.0,"abc00055":10.0,'abc00058":20.0],"td_cnt_sum":49}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy/agg` with `sum` and again `groupBy/agg` with `collect_list`

Here is an example'

You can read the json file as

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("read azure storage").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
val data = spark.read.json("path to json file ")
```

Since your data `m_cd` and `td_cnt` loads as `array` you need to select the first on if it always has one value otherwise **explode** to add the `array` values in `row`

```
val df = data.select(
  $"a_id", $"b_sum", $"m_cd" (0).as("m_cd"),
  $"td_cnt" (0).as("td_cnt"))
  .na.drop() //And also drop which has nulls in the value
```

Use groupy by twice to get th output

```
val df1 = df.groupBy("a_id", "m_cd")
  .agg(sum("td_cnt").as("td_cnt_sum"))
  .groupBy("a_id")
  .agg(collect_list(struct("m_cd", "td_cnt_sum")).as("td_cnt"), sum("td_cnt_sum").as("td_cnt_sum")
)

df1.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|a_id|td_cnt                                                             |td_cnt_sum|
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|6336|[[abc00056,30.0], [abc00053,15.0], [abc00054,20.0]]                |65.0      |
|6339|[[abc00055,10.0], [abc00051,12.0], [abc00057,7.0], [abc00058,20.0]]|49.0      |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Now you got the output now you can change your requirement.
Schema:

```
root
 |-- a_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- td_cnt: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- m_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- td_cnt_sum: double (nullable = true)
 |-- td_cnt_sum: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: did that helped ?

Comment: will this create a result like "td_cnt":[{"mcd":"abc00053","tdcnt_sum":15.0} , and the expected result is {"td_cnt":["abc00053":15.0

Comment: To get that result you can create an UDF and convert as your required format.